# Assigning MySQL query data into a temporary variable? VB.Net

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

I am almost completed creating a VB.Net application, it currently works fine on a single run basis, the program loads in records of data from a localhost server, and will add and remove data fine. But i would like to have the ID of the latest entered record saved so that when the program is closed for however long, program can be reopened, and pulls the latest ID number to increment by one before being inputted into the database.

I am inputting my "latest" ID number into its own seperate table than the main "Stock Data" table.

How do i load my "latest" ID number into a temporary variable in my app that i can..

extract old ID
increment ID by one
input new record with incremented ID
replace old ID with new ID in database

code for reference...

```
Mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection
Mysqlconn.ConnectionString="server=localhost;userid=root;password=P@ssw0rd;database=stocklist"
Dim READER As MySqlDataReader

Query = "use stocklist;select IDsave from saves;"
COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, Mysqlconn)
READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
```

Thank you in advance

Jay

Comment: The db is fully capable of incrementing an ID all by itself.  In fact, that is one of its jobs.  Rolling your own can easily fail in a variety of ways especially when you try to do it from the client app.

Answer (score 0):

Does your query result is always a single row?

If yes, then you have to use ExecuteScalar Function to get your data executed.

```
Mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection
Mysqlconn.ConnectionString="server=localhost;userid=root;password=P@ssw0rd;database=stocklist"
Dim READER As MySqlDataReader

Query = "use stocklist;select IDsave from saves;"
COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, Mysqlconn)
READER = Convert.ToString(COMMAND.ExecuteScalar())
```

If your READER variable is not string, please convert query result to corresponding one.